# shell how to fix file extension and remove duplicate

Tags: python, file, shell, file-extension

I have downloaded a lot of files using wget command from urls provided from imagenet file ([here](http://image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n02960352) is an example of car images). But when I check my files, I found that a lot of files, there are in wrong extension. For example, among the files, a file with extension '.jpg' is actually a text file. And I am aware that the --adjust-extension may only works well on .html and .css file.

So my question is with those files: 1. how could I recover the extension of files (including .jpg, .txt, .png, .html, etc.)? 2. some of the images may downloaded more than once, how to remove duplicates?

If it can be done in python is also fine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the file extension is messed up, you can use the unix program `file` to figure out the proper filetype. For usage, run `man file` from your shell.

Comment: You could use a checksum of the content or make a two step rocket and first check the file size and if two matches you do a checksum of the content and see if they match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a package like python-magic https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic or filemagic https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic which provide methods to identify a file based on contents.  The unix `file` command also words to find the file type with --mime-type flag.

As for duplicates, there are many utilities to do this, but to do it in python would go something like this:

```
import os, hashlib

def remove_dupes(dir):
    unique = set()
    for filename in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            filehash = hashlib.sha1(file(filename).read()).hexdigest()
            if filehash not in unique: 
                unique.add(filehash)
            else: 
                os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can the `file` command be used in pipe? I tried the following way, but did not work: `find ./aircon/ -name '*' | file -i`

Comment: No file doesn't take standard input, you need to use xargs like this:   `find /path/to/file -name 'filename' -print0 | xargs -0 file -i`

Comment: You can use file on a list of filenames by using the flag `-f`, the list can come from stdin (pipe), which is indicated by `-f -`. So you can use `find ./aircon/ -name '*' | file -if -`

Comment: Beware: different hashes guarantee that files are different, but collisions are possible. When hashes compare equal, you should compare the original files before removing one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  However I'm not exactly sure what you mean by comparing the originals

Comment: You can compare the full file content of the two files if the hashes match. This will protect against a hash collision. However the probability of getting a collision with sha1 is very very very low, so this is very much a hypothetical situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `file` program to figure out the file type based on the content of the file instead of the filename. File comes with pretty much every version of linux and unix, including BSD and OSX. If you use Windows, I think it's included in Cygwin.

With the flag `-i` you will get the output as a mimetype, and you can use the `mimetypes` module from the standard library to map mimetype to proper file extensions. This works fine for many file types.

This sample works in linux with python 3. It will output each file in the current directory and a list of probable file extensions.

```
import os, mimetypes, subprocess
for filename in os.listdir(): 
    mime = subprocess.check_output(['file', '-ib', filename]).decode().split(';')[0]
    print(filename, mimetypes.guess_all_extensions(mime.strip()))
```

Comment: Ah nice use of mimetypes library I didn't think of that

Comment: Thank you very much. For the last line of code `print(filename, mimetypes.guess_all_extensions(mime))`, it should be `print(filename, mimetypes.guess_all_extensions(mime[:-1]))`, otherwise the output will be empty. The content of mime is something like `u'text/html\n'`.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't get a trailing newline when I tested it, but maybe it's different with python 2? In any case, using `mime.strip()` is safer. It only strips away whitespace characters. I'm updating the answer to include that.